# How do I get rid of duplicate projects in Apple Aperture 3?

Tags: software, apple-aperture

I've done a lot of searching but haven't been able to find the answer to a problem I'm having. I have several projects in Aperture 3. I just noticed that three of those projects now have duplicates. If I rename a project, its duplicate also gets renamed. So, they're linked. If I go to delete one of the projects, I get a scary warning saying the images are referenced elsewhere. How do I get rid of these duplicates? Was it something I did?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1) Back up your aperture library.

2) Hold down "Command" and "Option" at the same time, while you click on the Aperture application to run it.

3) You are given a dialog box with the option to "Repair Permissions", "Repair Database", or "Rebuild Database".  Start with "Repair Database", and see how your library looks when that is done.

4) If that didn't fix the issue, try "Rebuild Database" - that may be slow (it took a 2TB Aperture library I have about 30 minutes to rebuild) but should resolve the issue if nothing else does.

Comment: This did the trick. I did a Repair Database and that fixed it. Thanks!

Comment: THANK YOU! I had duplicate folders in my library and the 'repair database' fixed this problem! Awesome!

Answer (score 0):

One of Apple's tricks is that it can do hard links to directories.  Normally this is not a good thing, as it's ambiguous what the proper parent directory is.

I suspect that you have managed to make one of these by mistake.

Try this:

- Create a new project.
- From ONE of the duplicates, select all images, and drag them to the new project.

If my hypothesis is correct they will disappear from both projects.

- Verify that the new project has the right number of images.
- Delete the old project.  Both of them if need be.
- Rename your new project to whatever name, and move it to whatever location you wish.